# DataLoading event is never fired

Tags: .net-core, devexpress, dashboard

I am trying to set a DashboardObjectDataSource to my dashboard and I would like to catch the DataLoading event to specify the datas depending on the dashboard selected. My problem is that DataLoading event is never fired.

I have tried subscribing to the event like this :

```
public DataSourceInMemoryStorage CreateDataSourceStorage()
    {
        DataSourceInMemoryStorage dataSourceStorage = new DataSourceInMemoryStorage();

        DashboardObjectDataSource data = new DashboardObjectDataSource();
        data.DataSource = typeof(Data);
        data.Name = "Object Data Source";
        dataSourceStorage.RegisterDataSource("dataSourceObject", data.SaveToXml());
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddDefaultDashboardController(configurator => {
                configurator.SetDashboardStorage(new DataBaseEditaleDashboardStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DashboardStorageConnection")));
                configurator.SetDataSourceStorage(CreateDataSourceStorage());
                configurator.AllowExecutingCustomSql = true;
            });

        services.AddDevExpressControls(settings => settings.Resources = ResourcesType.ThirdParty | ResourcesType.DevExtreme);

        DashboardConfigurator.PassCredentials = false;

        DashboardConfigurator.Default.DataLoading += Default_DataLoading;
    }

private static void Default_DataLoading(object sender, DataLoadingWebEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataSourceName == "Object Data Source")
        {
            e.Data = Data.GetData();
        }
    }

public class Data
{
    public static DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string query = "select TOP 1000 * from MyTable";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        da.Dispose();

        return dt;
    }
}
```

But I have never been able to enter in the Default_DataLoading method. I do not get any error, the dashboard is showing but without any datas.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the DashboardConfigurator.Default instance is causing the issue. Instead, define the DataLoading event handler in the AddDefaultDashboardController method:

```
configurator.SetDataSourceStorage(CreateDataSourceStorage());
configurator.AllowExecutingCustomSql = true;
configurator.DataLoading += (s, e) => {
    if (e.DataSourceName == "Object Data Source")
    {
        e.Data = Data.GetData();
    }
};
```

In addition, please check if your dashboard layout contains data source with the name specified in the DataLoading event handler ("*Object Data Source*"). If your dashboard does not have a data source, you will need to create one using the [Create a New Data Source](https://docs.devexpress.com/Dashboard/117003/creating-dashboards/creating-dashboards-on-the-web/providing-data/create-a-new-data-source) option in Web Designer.

Just in case: the sample Web Dashboard application created using the DevExpress Template Gallery (see [Create an ASP.NET MVC Dashboard Application](https://docs.devexpress.com/Dashboard/116313/getting-started/build-web-dashboard-applications/create-an-asp.net-mvc-dashboard-application)) includes the Object Data Source registration that fills dashboard items with data once you add a corresponding data source in design mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My dashboard is linked to the datasource named "Object Data Source" but even if it was not, it should stop on the breakpoint that I have added on the "if" statement in the Default_DataLoading.

Comment: It appears that the DashboardConfigurator.Default reference is causing the issue. Instead, include the DataLoading event handler in the AddDefaultDashboardController method definition. I have updated my original answer accordingly.